# Form tag value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
document.forms["regform"]["fname"].value;
```

In java script i get the value of input having name("fname") which is in the form having name("regform") by using the above statement. How can i get it in jQuery??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $('#regform').find('[name=fname]').val()

Comment: use IDs and class names for inputs, it'll be easier/faster to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $form = $('form[name="regform"]'),
    $fname = form.find('[name="fname"]');

alert($fname.val());


// or you can just do wrap the native DOM version:

var $input = $(document.forms["regform"]["fname"]);

alert($fname.val());
```